# How to add copyright notice (in a box with borders) at bottom of first page?

Tags: boxes, copyright

I want to add a box with some copyright statement at the bottom of my paper.
What is the easiest/best way to do this?

Ideally, the box would have the width of the text, and be horizontally centered.
Also, I don't want it to interact with any potential (IEEE-based) style files that might set footers etc.

(I've looked into the `fancyhdr` package, but `\fancyfoot{copyright statement...}` puts a footer at every page except the first one; and I only want the statement to appear  on the first page)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this in several ways; for example you can use the [textpos](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos), or the [atbegshi](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi) package, or [TikZ](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf). Here's an example using `TikZ`:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\copyrighttext{%
  \footnotesize text text text text text text text text text text text text
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
   text text}
\newcommand\copyrightnotice{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=south,yshift=10pt] at (current page.south) {\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-\fboxsep-\fboxrule\relax}{\copyrighttext}}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\copyrightnotice
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and clean solution. Do you see any (dis)advantage of using TikZ over the textpos solution I wrote down?

Comment: @Rabarberski: one disadvantage is that `PGF/TikZ` is a much "heavier" package to load than `textpos`.

Answer (score 11):

For IEEE conference format, you ca use:

```
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\IEEEpubid{\makebox[\columnwidth]{978-1-4799-2442-4/13/\$31.00 \copyright 2013 IEEE \hfill} \hspace{\columnsep}\makebox[\columnwidth]{ }}
```

just after:

```
\begin{document}
```

You can find some more practical information [in this blog post](http://www.stabeler.com/blog/541/), and in the original [IEEEtran class howto](http://controls.papercept.net/conferences/support/files/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf).

Comment: Is there a specific advantage to using the `\IEEEpubid`?

Comment: Worked perfect for me!

Answer (score 2):

I've been googling some more, and bumped into the package `textpos`, which gave me a workable solution (don't know if it is the 'best' one). It requires me to tweak the position and width of the box, but that's okay.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[absolute,showboxes]{textpos}

%set unit to be pagewidth and height, and increase inner margin of box
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{\paperwidth}\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\paperheight}
\TPMargin{5pt}

%define \copyrightstatement command for easier use
\newcommand{\copyrightstatement}{
    \begin{textblock}{0.84}(0.08,0.93)    % tweak here: {box width}(leftposition, rightposition)
         \noindent
         \footnotesize
         \copyright  IEEE, 2012. Blablablablabla ... more text goes here
    \end{textblock}
}


\begin{document}
     \copyrightstatement
     \title{Title of my paper}
     and all the rest...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Gonzalo's answer, it might be more handy to define the content as an argument to be passed in (here the new command takes [1] argument, which is then referred to as #1 in the command definition):

```
\newcommand\copyrightnotice[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=south,yshift=10pt] at (current page.south) {\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-\fboxsep-\fboxrule\relax}{#1}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Then just use it wherever as:
 `\copyrightnotice{PUT YOUR NOTICE HERE}`

Answer (score 0):

For IEEE conference template, add the following package:

```
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
```

Just after the `\begin{document}` add the following:

```
\makeatletter
\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
  \def\@oddfoot{\mycopyrightnotice}%
  \def\@evenfoot{}%
}
\def\mycopyrightnotice{
  {\footnotesize Blablablablabla... more text goes here. The copyright is with the IEEE. \hfill}
  \gdef\mycopyrightnotice{}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Rabarberski's 2012 question** (Belgium):
*I want to add a box with some copyright statement at the bottom of my paper. What is the easiest/best way to do this?*

The question has a parenthetical remark about **FancyHdr**, which would place the copyright in the **footer**. The accepted answer assumes that he wants the copyright in the footer. As his question is phrased, then the expected answer might be what appears in published books. The images below are of the copyright pages for **Conte-deBoor** (McGraw-Hill 1980). The LaTeX sources produced the images. Many books place the copyright notice on the back side of the title page. Using the sources, the copyright notice can be moved to the desired location.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[b6paper]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}\begin{center}
\huge\bf ELEMENTARY NUMERICAL ANALYSIS \\[2ex]
\large\bf An Algorithmic Approach \\
\large\rm Third Edition\\[2ex]
S. D. Conte, Purdue University \\
Carl de Boor, University of Wisconsin-Madison
\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
~\vfill% empty text at top of page
\large\bf ELEMENTARY NUMERICAL ANALYSIS\\
\normalsize\rm An Algorithmic Approach\\
Copyright \copyright  1980 by McGraw-Hill, inc. All rights reserved.\\[1pc]
234567890 DODO 89876543210
\end{center}\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image: Conte-deBoor copyright pages 1980 (reduced content)]

An **ANSWER** to the parenthetical question  about **fancyhdr.sty** modifies the code used for the first image. Only the **fancyhdr** package was added.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[b6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}\begin{center}
\huge\bf ELEMENTARY NUMERICAL ANALYSIS \\[2ex]
\large\bf An Algorithmic Approach \\
\large\rm Third Edition\\[2ex]
S. D. Conte, Purdue University \\
Carl de Boor, University of Wisconsin-Madison
\clearpage\thispagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize\rm 
  Copyright \copyright  1980 by McGraw-Hill, inc. All rights reserved.}
~\vfill% empty text at top of page
\large\bf ELEMENTARY NUMERICAL ANALYSIS\\
\normalsize\rm An Algorithmic Approach\\
234567890 DODO 89876543210
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
%\fancyfoot[C]{\relax}
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image: Conte-deBoor copyright pages 1980 (reduced content) using fancyhdr]

Comment: This does not answer the question as the OP explicitly wants the copyright notice at the bottom of a page and the mention of `fancyhdr` package hints that he wants it in the page footer.