# IEEEtran conference with \maketitle - copyright notice (in a box with borders) at bottom of first page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, ieeetran

Searching for a way to add copyright statement into IEEEtran conference document I came across [How to add copyright notice (in a box with borders) at bottom of first page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55813/how-to-add-copyright-notice-in-a-box-with-borders-at-bottom-of-first-page) which concerns exactly my problem. Unfortunately the solution with `TikZ` does not work with `\maketitle` used in the document - it creates new page before title page. Removing `\maketitle` eliminates the problem.

Any tip how to get copyright notice into the paper?

I cannot add comment in the above question so I need to ask another one.

The simplest example is:

```
%% bare_conf.tex
%% V1.4
%% 2012/12/27
%% by Michael Shell

\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

% *** IEEE Copyright notice with TikZ ***
% 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\copyrighttext{%
  \footnotesize \textcopyright 2012 IEEE. Personal use of this material is permitted.
  Permission from IEEE must be obtained for all other uses, in any current or future 
  media, including reprinting/republishing this material for advertising or promotional 
  purposes, creating new collective works, for resale or redistribution to servers or 
  lists, or reuse of any copyrighted component of this work in other works. 
  DOI: \href{<http://tex.stackexchange.com>}{<DOI No.>}}
\newcommand\copyrightnotice{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=south,yshift=10pt] at (current page.south) {\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-\fboxsep-\fboxrule\relax}{\copyrighttext}}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
% *** IEEE Copyright notice with TikZ ***
% 
\copyrightnotice

\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Conferences}

% make the title area
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
The abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

\subsection{Subsection Heading Here}
\lipsum[1-2]

\subsubsection{Subsubsection Heading Here}
\lipsum[1-2]

% that's all folks
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `\maketitle` in`IEEEtran` is defined in such a way that it issues a `\newpage` before putting the title and friends. I have included the definition for reference (from `IEEEtran`):

```
\def\maketitle{\par%
  \begingroup%
  \normalfont%
  \def\thefootnote{}%  the \thanks{} mark type is empty
  \def\footnotemark{}% and kill space from \thanks within author
  \let\@makefnmark\relax% V1.7, must *really* kill footnotemark to remove all \textsuperscript spacing as well.
  \footnotesize%       equal spacing between thanks lines
  \footnotesep 0.7\baselineskip%see global setting of \footnotesep for more info
  % V1.7 disable \thanks note indention for compsoc
  \@IEEEcompsoconly{\long\def\@makefntext##1{\parindent 1em\noindent\hbox{\@makefnmark}##1}}%
  \normalsize%
  \ifCLASSOPTIONpeerreview
     \newpage\global\@topnum\z@ \@maketitle\@IEEEstatictitlevskip\@IEEEaftertitletext%
     \thispagestyle{IEEEpeerreviewcoverpagestyle}\@thanks%
  \else
     \if@twocolumn%
        \ifCLASSOPTIONtechnote%
           \newpage\global\@topnum\z@ \@maketitle\@IEEEstatictitlevskip\@IEEEaftertitletext%
        \else
           \twocolumn[\@maketitle\@IEEEdynamictitlevspace\@IEEEaftertitletext]%
        \fi
     \else
        \newpage\global\@topnum\z@ \@maketitle\@IEEEstatictitlevskip\@IEEEaftertitletext%
     \fi
     \thispagestyle{IEEEtitlepagestyle}\@thanks%
  \fi
  % pullup page for pubid if used.
  \if@IEEEusingpubid
     \enlargethispage{-\@IEEEpubidpullup}%
  \fi 
  \endgroup
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}\let\maketitle\relax\let\@maketitle\relax
  \gdef\@thanks{}%
  % v1.6b do not clear these as we will need the title again for peer review papers
  % \gdef\@author{}\gdef\@title{}%
  \let\thanks\relax
}
```

If you issue `\copyrightnotice` before `\maketitle`, first the `tikzpicture` is put and a `\newpage` is issued by `\maketitle` resulting in copy right with its own page.

Hence put the `\copyrightnotice` after the `\maketitle`:

```
%% bare_conf.tex
%% V1.4
%% 2012/12/27
%% by Michael Shell

\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

% *** IEEE Copyright notice with TikZ ***
%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\copyrighttext{%
  \footnotesize \textcopyright 2012 IEEE. Personal use of this material is permitted.
  Permission from IEEE must be obtained for all other uses, in any current or future
  media, including reprinting/republishing this material for advertising or promotional
  purposes, creating new collective works, for resale or redistribution to servers or
  lists, or reuse of any copyrighted component of this work in other works.
  DOI: \href{<http://tex.stackexchange.com>}{<DOI No.>}}
\newcommand\copyrightnotice{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=south,yshift=10pt] at (current page.south) {\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-\fboxsep-\fboxrule\relax}{\copyrighttext}}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
% *** IEEE Copyright notice with TikZ ***
%
\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Conferences}
% make the title area
\maketitle
\copyrightnotice

\begin{abstract}
The abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

\subsection{Subsection Heading Here}
\lipsum[1-2]

\subsubsection{Subsubsection Heading Here}
\lipsum[1-2]

% that's all folks
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, that was lame. I checked it like 10 times and every time the copyright notice wasn't there. Now I tried it once more and still there was no notice. Then... I compiled it once more. The notice appeared. I've no idea why it didn't work before, I'm sure I compiled the source few times.
Thank you for the explanation with `IEEEtran` source!

Comment: @MateuszDziedzic When you use `[remember picture,overlay]` please compile at least 2-3 times (always) to get things settle down.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy: add the following line in the LaTeX document, but don't forget to include this package

```
\usepackage{eso-pic}

 \AddToShipoutPicture*{\small \sffamily\raisebox{1.2cm}{\hspace{1.8cm}978-1-4799-8641-5/15/\$31.00@2015 IEEE}}
```