# How to add Creative Commons licence to bottom of the page in the tufte-handout class?

Tags: tufte

I can't find a way to add a notice to the bottom of the first page. I tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55813/how-to-add-copyright-notice-in-a-box-with-borders-at-bottom-of-first-page) but it just flushes all content to the second page and adds the box at the bottom of the first.

EDIT: some sample code.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\makeatletter
\minted@define@extra{label}
\makeatother
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\usemintedstyle{tango}
\newminted{cpp}{}
\newmint{cpp}{}
\usepackage[portuguese,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\copyrighttext{%
  \footnotesize text text text text text text text text text text text text
  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
  text text}
\newcommand\copyrightnotice{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=south,yshift=10pt] at (current page.south) {\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-\fboxsep-\fboxrule\relax}{\copyrighttext}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\title{Best title ever}
\author{Me}
\begin{document}
\copyrightnotice
\maketitle
\section{Things}
text text text text text text
\section{Stuff}
text text text text
```

\end{document}

Generates these two pages:
[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can you show us what you've tried already by providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? It will be much easier for us to help you once we see your basic document setup, beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code does what you need; simply use `\copyrightnotice` *after* `\maketitle`:

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\usepackage[portuguese,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\copyrighttext{%
  \footnotesize text text text text text text text text text text text text
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
   text text}
\newcommand\copyrightnotice{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=south,yshift=10pt,draw] 
    at (current page.south) 
    {\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-\fboxsep-\fboxrule\relax}{\copyrighttext}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\title{Best title ever}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\copyrightnotice
\section{Things}
    text text text text text text
\section{Stuff}
    text text text text

\end{document}
```

[image]